# can image.src be a security risk?

Tags: javascript, html

i have the following code

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://MyTrackingSite.com/?myTrackingParameter=whatever"
```

the image is not added to the Dom-Tree. Is it rendered by the command "image.src" ?  can it be a security risk ?

Cheers

Arne

Comment: What kind of security risk are you talking about?

Comment: The code as shown makes the browser request the given URL – that’s the basic principle behind almost every JavaScript “image preloading” script. Whether that affects “security” depends on what exactly you mean by the word in this specific context.

Comment: if the image is rendered,the rendering of a prepared image can lead to a bufferoverflow, which can crash the browser, can't it ?

Comment: @user3036353 In modern browsers, not really.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the code above will [preload the image](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/). In this specific case, it forces the browser to make a request to the tracking site.

The security risk is low unless:

1. The tracking site was hacked or is not genuine in the first place. [The New York Times was once hit with something like this](http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/09/14/times-site-was-victim-of-a-malicious-ad-swap/?_php=true&_type=blogs&_r=0), so it's rare but not impossible.
2. No one intercepts your traffic and replaces the image the original server sent you ([some agencies around the globe intercept traffic to YouTube and similar sites to hack computers](http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/spyware-tools-allow-buyers-to-slip-malicious-code-into-youtube-videos-microsoft-pages/2014/08/15/31c5696c-249c-11e4-8593-da634b334390_story.html?tid=pm_world_pop))
3. You don't run the latest version of your browser
4. You don't have the latest security patches for your OS installed
5. If you run Windows or Mac OS, you should have a virus protection installed and you should check every now and then if it's still active, working, and up to date (both the software and it's virus patterns).

Most of the time, it's just a privacy leak since the tracking site just returns a web bug (1x1 transparent image). The goal of the code is to let the tracker know where you were.